# Writing a basic Expression Builder

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-entities

I am using Linq-to-Entities and one query requires a property to be loaded dynamically. The query looks like this:

```
var found = Context.IntegrateViews.GroupBy(x => x.TypeOfBed)
                   .Select(type => new TypeCounts
                            { Name = type.Key, Count = type.Count() }).ToList();
```

The property on which Group By clause is being run is TypeOfBed. Now I want to run this query on different properties e.g., next time I want to run it on, let's say x.TypeOfChair and so on. For this, I need to have this property in there dynamically.

I am trying to write a Expression builder which is like this.

```
public Expression<Func<LookupFilterItem>> PropertyLambda(string propertyName)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(LookupFilterItem), "lookupItem");
    //type of x in above example is LookupFilterItem
    var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(param, propertyName);

    var returnExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<LookupFilterItem>>(propertyExpression);
    return returnExpr;
    //If I Pass string "TypeOfBed" to this method, I am expecting it to return something like
    // lookupItem => lookupItem.TypeOfBed
}
```

And I intend to use it like this:

```
var found = Context.IntegrateViews.GroupBy(PropertyLambda("TypeOfBed"))
                   .Select(type => new TypeCounts
                            { Name = type.Key, Count = type.Count() }).ToList();
```

But this is not working, I am getting a compile time error which says:

> error CS0411: The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Queryable.GroupBy(System.Linq.IQueryable,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot
>   be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a syntax issue. Try this:

```
public Expression<Func<LookupFilterItem, string>> PropertyLambda(string propertyName)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(LookupFilterItem), "lookupItem");
        var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(param, propertyName);
        var returnExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<LookupFilterItem, string>>(propertyExpression, param);
        return returnExpr;
    }
```

And the usage:

```
var found = Context.IntegrateViews.GroupBy(PropertyLambda("TypeOfBed").Compile())
               .Select(type => new TypeCounts
                        { Name = type.Key, Count = type.Count() }).ToList();
```

Comment: @Aamir  By compiling the expression it forces everything to be done using LINQ to objects, rather than the query provider, completely defeating the purpose of using expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [LINQ Dynamic Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) :

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

var found = Context.IntegrateViews.AsQueryable().GroupBy("new(TypeOfBed)", "it")
                   .Select(new (Key.TypeOfBed as Name, Count() as Count)).ToList();
```